# Display custom position on Kendo Loading Indicator

Tags: kendo-ui, progress

how to change Kendo Loading position ? The middle is always

kendo.ui.progress($("#main-content"), true);

kendo.ui.progress($("#main-content"), false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a style to the k-loading-image element to specify the position of its background image(which is the loading spinner), i.e.

```
#main-content > .k-loading-mask > .k-loading-image {
    background-position-x: 10px;
    background-position-y: 10px;
}
```

Example: http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/iKiCI